# No handlers could be found for logger "django_facebook.models"

Tags: django-facebook

while installing django_facebook, i got an error :

```
Validating models...

No handlers could be found for logger "django_facebook.models"
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x1032a5758>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 93, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 101, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 310, in validate
num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 113, in get_validation_errors
from django.utils.image import Image
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/image.py", line 154, in <module>
Image, _imaging, ImageFile = _detect_image_library()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/image.py", line 108, in _detect_image_library
    _("Neither Pillow nor PIL could be imported: %s") % err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Neither Pillow nor PIL could be imported: No module named Image
```

It is a pure django project created by pycharm. I was following the document of django_facebook, installation section. What I do is just get facebook app and type the code 'django_facebook' in INSTALLED_APP in settings.py.
It's same results when syncdb also.

I'm using python-2.7.5 and django-1.6.5. 
I can't find any answer to solve this. anybody knows this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Regarding the warning**`No handlers could be found for logger "django_facebook.models"` **and not the error.** This question came up on search for that warning, thought this would be useful for others.

django-facebook outputs logs when in operation, just like other django components do. You have to tell Django what you want to do with these messages. In django terminology the app outputs some messages as a *logger* without needing to know what to do with them, you have to then patch these to a *handler* which doesn't know anything about your use case, but does know about sending emails/texts/carrier pigeons.

In your `settings.py` file find `LOGGING=...`, in the `loggers` dict you will have to specify what handlers you want to handle the output from django-facebook.

For more information see the docs on logging https://djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

My logging variable looks like this, notice the bit at the bottom:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins','console'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django_facebook.models': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins','console'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `pip install pillow`

Comment: Perhaps you might explain why it would be helpful? And format the output?

Comment: Thx mana!
Actually, it was my fault to catch the point of problem. the progress could be kept going even if with that message 'No handler could be blahblah'. I could do my work again with "pip install pillow".
and still that "No handler ~~~" exists but no problem for me just now. thank you.